# Update bean properties on button click

Tags: zk

I'm new to ZK framework and trying to implement a simple thing but ZK's different approach is boggling my mind:

I have a grid with a model as a Person list. All grid fields are editable textboxes and are populated with Person's name and surname (2 columns). What I'm trying to do is:

-- Implement a "Save All" button, which will bind all changed values to respecting Person's name and surname properties.

Simply, on "Save All" click, save all changed values. But I don't want to  change anything before button click, so there will be no @save on textboxes, just @load.

What I did so far:
-- On textboxes' onChange event, save textbox's value on a temporary Person object's property (either name or surname), and add that Person to a changedPersonsList. On SaveAll button's click, replace my model's Persons with changedPersonsList Persons... But then I can't know which Person is which without implementing an ID field.

Everything would be SOO easy if I just can send label values on SaveAll click along with row number.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the timing of data binding with *condition keywords*..

```
<textbox value="@load(vm.text) @save(vm.text, before='saveAll')"/>
<button onClick="@command('saveAll')"/>
```

Here we use the `before` condition to coordinate when the value should be saved: not when it is changing (like normal) but when the `saveAll` command is about to be executed.

You can read more about this in the [ZK documentation](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/MVVM/Data%20Binding/Property%20Binding#Conditional_Binding).

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I was starting to get worried about no one answering questions about ZK neither on SO nor on ZK forums. Challenging part is how to track changes on grid cells WITHOUT saving them directly to model. I have tried form binding on each row, and then gone as far as using reflection. I'm simply trying to add a "Save All" button to this example : http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/grid/inline_editing without committing any changes before button click.